# Excel VBA: columns are filled with invisible content until the end (column 16,384)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file for budgeting with lots of VBA programming in the background. The file allows for various importations/exportations to be done and works quite well, but once the number of projects (each project has 15 worksheets) gets too high it gets messy.

A lot of times I get an error message that either says "Cannot shift object off sheet" or "Excel has too few resources to complete the task". In both cases Google says that the problem is that I am exceeding the maximun number of columns or rows. And it is true - if I run a macro to find my last column with content it returns 16,384.

But I only put data in columns A to BA... as for the rows, the maximum row with content is 2,000. I don't see any content, I don't have any makros referencing "lastrow/lastcolumn" ... no idea what is happening. And sometimes I can manually delete a bunch of rows and columns and then it works; sometimes I have to manually recreate the workbook.

I know this is a very vague explanation, but I have about 15,000 lines of code behind, so quite complex to explain.

Maybe someone can still help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with Excel files. If the `UsedRange` is out of bounds, the file becomes bloated for no apparent reason.

This should fix it:

```
Sub ResetUsedRange()

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Dim lng As Long

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        lng = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Next

End Sub
```

If, for some reason, this doesn't help, just try to manually delete all the blank rows/columns at bottom/right of the data areas, hit save and check the file size afterwards.

Code taken from [here](https://chandoo.org/wp/big-trouble-in-little-spreadsheet/).

**Edit #1**

This augmented code will delete all empty rows and columns on each sheet in the workbook outside the used range and attempt to reset the `UsedRange` afterwards. Remember to back up your file **before** executing the code and that the decrease in file size only occurs after you save the file. Depending on the number of sheets, it may take a while to complete.

```
Sub DeleteBlankRowsAndColumnsAndResetUsedRange()

    Dim rangeBool As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, lng As Long, tempRwsCount As Long
    Dim tempRng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        On Error Resume Next
        lastRow = sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
        lastCol = sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        tempRwsCount = sht.Rows.count

        If lastRow > 0 And lastRow < tempRwsCount Then
            ' delete empty rows and columns
            Set tempRng = sht.Rows(lastRow + 1 & ":" & tempRwsCount)
            tempRng.Delete
            Set tempRng = sht.Columns(lastCol + 1).Resize(, sht.Columns.count - lastCol)
            tempRng.Delete

        End If

        ' reset used range
        lng = sht.UsedRange.Rows.count

    Next sht

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit #2**

Thanks to `Shawn V. Wilson`' for pointing out that it is necessary to save the file and then **close and reopen** it to see the changes in file size.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this right away. Does it work as well with Columns, replacing "Rows" with "Columns" in the code above?

Comment: Please try the new code. It works for both columns and rows.

Comment: Important add on to where @Miqi180 said "If, for some reason, this doesn't help, just try to manually delete all the blank rows/columns at bottom/right of the data areas, hit save and check the file size afterwards."   (a) Remember you have to actually delete the whole rows and columns, not just clear their contents. (b) You can't just save the file. You have to close it and reopen it in order to reset the where the "last cell" is.

Comment: @Shawn V. Wilson Thanks for pointing this out. I made a second edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I will save the new code for the next time!
In the end, the original code worked for about 90% of my sheets and I dealt with the rest manually (deleting all columns from BX until the end, saving, closing and opening the file again).

Comment: Great. You might consider accepting my answer then. Thx